# BigQuery Invalid field name _PARTITIONDATE or _PARTITIONTIME

Tags: google-bigquery

In a date partitioned table, you should be able to run:

```sql
    SELECT
      _PARTITIONDATE,
      COUNT(*)
    FROM table
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY 1
```

However, running this command will return an error:

```
Invalid field name "_PARTITIONDATE". Field names are not allowed to start with the (case-insensitive) prefixes _PARTITION, _TABLE_, _FILE_ and _ROW_TIMESTAMP
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out, all you need to do is provide an alias for the  the `_PARTITIONDATE` or `_PARTITIONTIME` columns in your query:

```sql
SELECT 
    -- _PARTITIONDATE alone will not work
    _PARTITIONDATE as partition_date,
    COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: this is called - provide alias! renaming does not really applicable here :o)